# What exactly does it mean when you have a const object {} = {} another object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

1. I don't really understand what is happening in this piece of code, what does it mean when you do const objName {} = {} ?

```
    import RedisCache from '@model/redis.model';

    const redisService: {
        client: RedisCache['client'];
        init: () => Promise<RedisCache['client']>;
        get: (key: string) => Promise<string | JSON | object>;
        set: (key: string, value: string | object) => Promise<string | object>;
        delete: (key: string) => Promise<number>;
        key: (exact: string, like: string) => Promise<string[]>;
    } = {
        client: null,
        init: () =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Promise.resolve(new RedisCache().connect())
                    .then((client: any) => {
                        redisService.client = client;
                        resolve(redisService.client);
                    })
                    .catch(err => reject(err));
            })
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] where the only issues present are the ones you are asking about.  The particular code you are referencing is syntactically invalid, and refers to undeclared names like `RedisCache`.

Comment: For example, maybe you'd have the same question about `const foo: { bar: string; baz: number; } = { bar: "hey", baz: 123 };`?  If so, I can answer that.  If not, please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, let me post with more detail.

Comment: Can you confirm that you'd have the same question about `const foo: { bar: string; baz: number; } = { bar: "hey", baz: 123 };` which is a [mcve] and can be demonstrated in a standalone IDE like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGBvGAjAhgJxdHASzAHMBuTLALxTAFcBbDAUxwoF8YBeNSvGAEQALZgE8BAGko0YARgBMAZhjsKQA)?

Comment: I believe so, yes. Is it essentially saying that init will be of type Promise?

Comment: `init` will be of type `() => Promise<RedisCache['client']>` meaning, "a function which takes no parameters, and returns a `Promise` of a particular type".  The type of the data returned in that `Promise` will be `RedisCache["client"]`, which is whatever the type of the `client` property of a `RedisCache` value will be.  Without a [mcve] including `RedisCache` I can't be more explicit here.

Comment: Okay, that clears some things up, thank you